# Как адекватно работать с Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spa

Приветствую, собственно в чем моя проблема. Никак не могу адекватно заставить работать Hibernate. Может кто-нибудь может рассказать рецепт подхода к нему, не прошу код, просто что, как настроить что бы не ловить всякие проблемы.

Что у меня есть:

> Сущности, со связями. fetch везде LAZY, cascade = ALL
>
> Пара методов, реализованых в стиле отрыть сессию, сохранить/получить,
>   комит. Дальше сессию забирает мой велосипед, который закрывает их
>   через 10 секунд.
>
> Тесты, которые паралельно начинают лупить во все методы DAO,

Время от времени эти тесты получают:

> LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
>
> LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> а источних их HsqlException: transaction rollback: serialization
>   failure

Все настолько плохо, что я уже в проперти вкрутил

```
<property name="jta.UserTransaction">8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">8</property>
hsqldb.tx=mvcc
```

и черт, мне кажется он их игнорирует. Или я не понимаю, почему при SERIALIZATION уровне он может ловить проблемы с транзакциями?

Если надо, я могу скинуть код. Хотя я же просто про подход спрашиваю :)

Comment: Вероятно транзакции конфликтуют. Пытаются одновременно изменять какие-то записи. Или одна меняет, а другая в это время пытается их прочитать. Но из-за блокировок и высокого уровня изоляции возникает конфликт. Второй транзакции база данных выписывает фигвам. Уровень serializable не всеми базами поддерживается честным образом. У них на самом деле транзакции не ждут друг друга, а выполняются всегда параллельно. Успешно завершается только одна, другие отклоняются при попытке завершить. Главное же обеспечить условие отсутствия/наличия всяких феноменов при успешном завершении.

Comment: Рекомендую вам запустить tracer на базе данных, чтобы отловить события, которые происходят при активной работе вашего приложения. Пример tracer для microsoft sql server - это Profiler. Если у Вас другая СУБД, то используйте другой. Тогда вы явно увидите что Hibernate делает в Вашей базе данных.

Comment: Плюс бывают ошибки, когда остаются открытые транзакции, при использовании явного транзакционного режима работы. В этом случае у вас действительно могут быть конфликты с несколькими открытыми транзакциями. Почитайте про org.hibernate.Session.beginTransaction() и org.hibernate.Transaction.commit().
Также можно проверять открытые сессии Session и транзакции Transaction:
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
и
        if (currentTransaction != null && currentTransaction.isActive()) {
            currentTransaction.commit();
        }

Comment: А что почитать про beginTransaction и commit? JavaDoc их видел, думал достаточно)
Для HSQLDB не нашел tracer'а.

Comment: Комментарии о блокировках в базе нагнали на мысль.
Выставил у HSQLDB принудительно hsqldb.tx_level=read_commited
Изоляции переставил в 4 (REPEATABLE_READ)
И о чудо, эта комбинация за 30 запусков тестов не разу не завалилась.
Но вот и назрел вопрос, в базе стоит read_commited, в хибернейте REPEATABLE_READ. И так работает, а по другому нет. Что же это за аномалия такая? Законна ли она? Или я там совсем НЛО соорудил?